# Promise execution order (JS)

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

I've got confused when trying to explain the order of promises' execution in the following case (I expected the order to be (1,2,3), but it happens to be (1,3,2) ):

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  const res = 1;
  console.log(res);
  resolve(Promise.resolve(res));
}).then((res) => {
  const newRes = res * 2;
  console.log(newRes);
});

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(3));
```

I am aware that promise handlers are placed in the microtask queue and that the code inside promise callback ctors executes synchronously. Thus I believe that this code:

```
  const res = 1;
  console.log(res);
  resolve(Promise.resolve(res));
```

executes in the first place.

**However**, it is obvious that the `resolve(Promise.resolve(res))` method in the code above actually produces another promise, whose handler (implicit one that will be called later) I believe is being placed in the microtask queue immediately.

Whatever it happens to be, JS engine continues to process the code line by line. Thus I also believe that the next promise handler to be placed in the microtask queue is the following one:

```
.then((res) => {
  const newRes = res * 2;
  console.log(newRes);
});
```

At last, `.then(() => console.log(3));` is being placed in the microtask queue.

Obviously there is a gap in my understanding of promises. Can please someone explain in which part(-s) I am wrong?

Comment: Why does it even matter? You have two independent promise chains. There should be no expectation at all which of them runs its asynchronous handlers first.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761840/promise-then-with-a-function-returning-nothing-vs-with-a-function-returning-another-promise, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217603/what-is-the-difference-between-returned-promise and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408228/es6-promise-execution-order-for-returned-values

Comment: You do not need that `Promise.resolve` wrapper in the constructor function. Removing it gives the order you expect, as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: "*I also believe that the next promise handler to be placed in the microtask queue is the following one*" - no. That promise handler is not placed in the queue until the promise it was registered on is actually fullfilled.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot! Now the execution order becomes clear to me.