Event loop: execution order
I'm having a hard time understanding the execution order of the code that has asynchronous elements in it. Here's the problematic code:
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, _){
    resolve('microtask2');
}).then((res)=> {
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err)=> console.error(`caught an ${err}`));

const timer = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('set timeout');
}, 0);

for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    console.log(`cicle 1: ${i}`);
}

const result = await new Promise(function(resolve, _){
    try{
        resolve('microtask1');
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(`caught an ${err}`);
    }
});


for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    console.log(`cicle 2: ${i}`);
}

At the beginning I thought that event loop executes code in the following order:

all synchronous code
microtask queue
macrotask queue

And it appears to work exactly so if I comment out result promise:
output: loop1 --> loop2 --> microtask2 --> set timeout

But if I keep the result the callback from multitask is printed out in between the loops (where it is defined) without waiting for all the synchronous code to finish:
output: loop1 --> microtask2 --> loop2 --> set timeout

What am I missing here? Is this behaviour somehow related to the blocking nature of await?

Edit to address trinkot's commentary:
"Statements that follow after an await are executed later, asynchronously. Always"
If you run this code you will see that fetch() immediately returns the promise (1-2 miliseconds) and then the synchronous code continues:
const start1 = performance.now();
const promise = fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
promise.then(
    (res) => console.log(`(then) result ${res} retrieved in ${Math.round(performance.now()-start1)} milis`)
);
console.log(`fetching took ${Math.round(performance.now() - start1)} milis`);
console.log('synchronous code continues...');

In the case of await this doesn't seem to happen. It looks like await blocks the thread until the promise is settled:
const start2 = performance.now();
const result = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
console.log(`fetching and resolving took ${Math.round(performance.now() - start2)} milis`);
console.log('synchronous code continues...');
console.log(`(await) result ${result} retrieved in ${Math.round(performance.now()-start2)} milis`);

Here's the output:
then:

await:

P.S. If I'm missing the point, please, don't get frustrated, I'm new to JS.

Why are there loops that iterate 1000 times? Is this relevant in some way?

This topic is already well covered here, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408228/es6-promise-execution-order-for-returned-values and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923253/in-what-order-are-promise-callbacks-triggered and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217603/what-is-the-difference-between-returned-promise

"without waiting for all the synchronous code to finish": Statements that follow after an await are executed later, asynchronously. Always.

@trincot, I edited my post. Please, take a look

"It looks like await blocks the thread until the promise is settled": the thread is not blocked. There is just no code to execute while the JavaScript event loop checks for jobs.

Also, in the second variant (with await) the output "synchronous code continues..." is made in code that we label "asynchronous" (because it is placed after an await). In the first variant, you are outputting "fetching took 1 milis", at a moment fetch did not yet get a response.
